# Mulitple ISP IP's pointing to one router

Tags: networking, ip, isp

My `ISP` is providing me with two **dynamic** and one static **IP**.

My question is: ***How is it possible to have three IP's, but i only have one router?***

Or is it that i can only have a static or a dynamic ip pointing to router? 
Do i have to have a router for every IP that I get from `ISP`?

Thanks for helping a newbie :)

Comment: Someone with better ability to answer a networking questions can answer this better than I can.  However, IP addresses are not limited to one per device.  Devices such as network cards, routers, etc can have multiple IPs.  And as far as I know, a device can have virtually unlimited IP addresses.

Comment: Most home grade routes can only handle one WAN IP (with default firmware, some extended firmwares are more capable). If you want to use all 3 IPs, DDWRT or tomato will do a better job, or upgrade your router, but you really only need one router if you only want to use one IP.

Comment: It's not an unusual situation in a business environment although I've usually had a small group of static IPs rather than a mix. If you only have one LAN socket on the router you just plug in a switch and connect multiple devices to that.

Answer (score 0):

They just direct traffic to all those IPs to your router. You don't have to have a router for every IP, just as your ISP doesn't have one router for every IP. The whole point of a router is to direct traffic to various different IP addresses.